# Extend numpy mask by n cells to the right for each bad value, efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, bigdata

Let's say I have a length 30 array with 4 bad values in it. I want to create a mask for those bad values, but since I will be using rolling window functions, I'd also like a fixed number of subsequent indices after each bad value to be marked as bad. In the below, n = 3:

[image]

I would like to do this as efficiently as possible because this routine will be run many times on large data series containing billions of datapoints. Thus I need as close to a numpy vectorized solution as possible because I'd like to avoid python loops.

For avoidance of retyping, here is the array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([4, 0, 8, 5, 10, 9, np.nan, 1, 4, 9, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 9,\
              9, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 2, 6, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 1, np.nan, 10])
```

Comment: Is there anything you've tried yourself already?

Comment: Have you thought about all the fancy indexing forms that Python and numpy allow?

Comment: he has clearly put some thought into it since he drew the graphic and has the bit of code with a small example array ..

Comment: @ Evert: yes clearly I could loop through each bad index value and add [1, 2, 3] to each one, take the set of all of these (ie uniques) and use that as the mask bad value index. But that requires a loop. If I have 1m datapoints and 100k bad values, you can see how my looping is going to take a lot of time, and this is in a machine learning context so there will be lots of repetition of this routine. Happy to hear more about the fancy indexing possibilities. 
Guess I could using a pandas rolling apply but that's still a loop (though since implemented in C might be fast). Anything purely vector?

Comment: (afaik even "purely vector" is implemented in a loop in c land :P )

Comment: @Joran Beasley. Actually if you buy the MKL-linked version of Numpy (Anaconda Accelerate) lots of vectorized stuff is passed to the Intel AVX instruction set. Can speed things up 4-5x on my i7 versus non-MKL in Ubuntu and OS/X. But yes... I hear you ;-)

Comment: With irregular intervals you really can't make it 'purely vector' (i.e. rectangular).  The best you can do is use a compiled loop, such as @askewchan's `reduceat`.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne. My answer is a few years late, but do you think you could add it to the benchmark? I really like how you did it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'll give you an upvote for sure, but I am afraid I don't know where the code is anymore. I'll hunt around my Dropbox and see what I can do. No promises.
edit: Code is in my own answer ;-) Let me play around later this weekend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yet another answer!
It just takes the mask you already have and applies logical or to shifted versions of itself. Nicely vectorized and insanely fast! :D

```
def repeat_or(a, n=4):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    k = m.copy()

    # lenM and lenK say for each mask how many
    # subsequent Trues there are at least
    lenM, lenK = 1, 1

    # we run until a combination of both masks will give us n or more
    # subsequent Trues
    while lenM+lenK < n:
        # append what we have in k to the end of what we have in m
        m[lenM:] |= k[:-lenM]

        # swap so that m is again the small one
        m, k = k, m

        # update the lengths
        lenM, lenK = lenK, lenM+lenK

    # see how much m has to be shifted in order to append the missing Trues
    k[n-lenM:] |= m[:-n+lenM]

    return k
```

Unfortunately I couldn't get `m[i:] |= m[:-i]` running... probably a bad idea to both modify and use the mask to modify itself. It does work for `m[:-i] |= m[i:]`, however this is the wrong direction.
Anyway, instead of quadratic growth we now have Fibonacci-like growth which is still better than linear.
*(I never thought I'd actually write an algorithm that is really related to the Fibonacci sequence without being some weird math problem.)*

Testing under "real" conditions with array of size 1e6 and 1e5 NANs:

```
In [5]: a = np.random.random(size=1e6)

In [6]: a[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(a), dtype=int), 1e5, replace=False)] = np.nan

In [7]: %timeit reduceat(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 65.2 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit index_expansion(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit cumsum_trick(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 17 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit repeat_or(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit agml_indexing(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.91 ms per loop
```

I'll leave further benchmarks to Thomas.

Comment: You've joined the competition. Can't keep up. Bench results tomorrow!

Comment: I think you wanted m = np.isnan(a) on line 2.

Comment: Of course! :D   
That happens when you don't use copy and paste and just write from memory...

Comment: This is conceptually the same as @AGML's second answer, but avoids the costly boolean indexing.

Comment: Well if you see shifting the mask as the same concept then yes. But imho our implementations are quite different. :) Btw. AGML doesn't use boolean indexing but direct indexing. They need to both increment the indices every iteration and then use them to index the mask and set corresponding values to `True`. I'll add some more optimization in a few minutes so it scales better with `n`, this will not be possible with AGML's current solution.

Comment: Haha, sorry I meant specifically imply that the implementation was quite different. Also you're right, I meant "fancy" indexing (by array of indices), which I believe is still much slower than slicing, even if it's not as slow as a boolean array. A line profile would be interesting though :P

Comment: looks like you're the fastest.

Answer (score 5):

OP here with the benchmark results. I have included my own ("op") which I had started out with, which loops over the bad indices and adds 1...n to them then takes the uniques to find the mask indices. You can see it in the code below with all the other responses.

Anyway here are the results. The facets are size of array along x (10 thru 10e7) and size of window along y(5, 50, 500, 5000). Then it's by coder in each facet, with a log-10 score because we're talking microseconds through minutes.

[image]

@swenzel appears to be the winner with his second answer, displacing @moarningsun's first answer (moarningsun's second answer was crashing the machine through massive memory use, but that's probably because it was not designed for large n or non-sparse a).

The chart does not do justice to the fastest of these contributions because of the (necessary) log scale. They're dozens, hundreds of times faster than even decent looping solutions. swenzel1 is 1000x faster than op in the largest case, and op is already making use of numpy.

Please note that I have used a numpy version compiled against the optimised Intel MKL libraries which make full use of the AVX instructions present since 2012. In some vector use cases this will increase an i7/Xeon speed by a factor of 5. Some of the contributions may be benefitting more than others.

Here is the full code to run all the submitted answers so far, including my own. Function allagree() makes sure that results are correct, while timeall() will give you a long-form pandas Dataframe with all the results in seconds.

You can rerun it fairly easily with new code, or change my assumptions. Please keep in mind I did not take into account other factors such as memory usage. Also, I resorted to R ggplot2 for the graphic as I don't know seaborn/matplotlib well enough to make it do what I want.

For completeness, all the results agree:

```
In [4]: allagree(n = 7, asize = 777)
Out[4]:
             AGML0 AGML1 askewchan0 askewchan1 askewchan2 moarningsun0  \
AGML0         True  True       True       True       True         True
AGML1         True  True       True       True       True         True
askewchan0    True  True       True       True       True         True
askewchan1    True  True       True       True       True         True
askewchan2    True  True       True       True       True         True
moarningsun0  True  True       True       True       True         True
swenzel0      True  True       True       True       True         True
swenzel1      True  True       True       True       True         True
op            True  True       True       True       True         True

             swenzel0 swenzel1    op
AGML0            True     True  True
AGML1            True     True  True
askewchan0       True     True  True
askewchan1       True     True  True
askewchan2       True     True  True
moarningsun0     True     True  True
swenzel0         True     True  True
swenzel1         True     True  True
op               True     True  True
```

Thank you to all who submitted!

Code for the graphic after exporting output of timeall() using pd.to_csv and read.csv in R:

```
ww <- read.csv("ww.csv")    
ggplot(ww, aes(x=coder, y=value, col = coder)) + geom_point(size = 3) + scale_y_continuous(trans="log10")+ facet_grid(nsize ~ asize) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ggtitle("Fastest by coder") + ylab("time (seconds)")
```

Code for the test:

```
# test Stack Overflow 32706135 nan shift routines

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from timeit import Timer
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import morphology
import itertools
import pdb
np.random.seed(8472)


def AGML0(a, n):                               # loop itertools
    maskleft = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
    maskright = maskleft + n
    mask = np.zeros(len(a),dtype=bool)
    for l,r in itertools.izip(maskleft,maskright): 
        mask[l:r] = True
    return mask


def AGML1(a, n):                               # loop n
    nn = n - 1
    maskleft = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
    ghost_mask = np.zeros(len(a)+nn,dtype=bool)
    for i in range(0, nn+1):
        thismask = maskleft + i
        ghost_mask[thismask] = True
    mask = ghost_mask[:len(ghost_mask)-nn]
    return mask


def askewchan0(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    i = np.arange(1, len(m)+1)
    ind = np.column_stack([i-n, i]) # may be a faster way to generate this
    ind.clip(0, len(m)-1, out=ind)
    return np.bitwise_or.reduceat(m, ind.ravel())[::2]


def askewchan1(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    s = np.full(n, True, bool)
    return ndimage.binary_dilation(m, structure=s, origin=-(n//2))


def askewchan2(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    s = np.zeros(2*n - n%2, bool)
    s[-n:] = True
    return morphology.binary_dilation(m, selem=s)


def moarningsun0(a, n):
    mask = np.isnan(a)
    cs = np.cumsum(mask)
    cs[n:] -= cs[:-n].copy()
    return cs > 0


def moarningsun1(a, n):
    mask = np.isnan(a)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    expanded_idx = idx[:,None] + np.arange(1, n)
    np.put(mask, expanded_idx, True, 'clip')
    return mask


def swenzel0(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    k = m.copy()
    for i in range(1, n):
        k[i:] |= m[:-i]
    return k


def swenzel1(a, n=4):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    k = m.copy()

    # lenM and lenK say for each mask how many
    # subsequent Trues there are at least
    lenM, lenK = 1, 1

    # we run until a combination of both masks will give us n or more
    # subsequent Trues
    while lenM+lenK < n:
        # append what we have in k to the end of what we have in m
        m[lenM:] |= k[:-lenM]

        # swap so that m is again the small one
        m, k = k, m

        # update the lengths
        lenM, lenK = lenK, lenM+lenK

    # see how much m has to be shifted in order to append the missing Trues
    k[n-lenM:] |= m[:-n+lenM]
    return k


def op(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    for x in range(1, n):
        m = np.logical_or(m, np.r_[False, m][:-1])
    return m


# all the functions in a list. NB these are the actual functions, not their names
funcs = [AGML0, AGML1, askewchan0, askewchan1, askewchan2, moarningsun0, swenzel0, swenzel1, op]

def allagree(fns = funcs, n = 10, asize = 100):
    """ make sure result is the same from all functions """
    fnames = [f.__name__ for f in fns]
    a = np.random.rand(asize)
    a[np.random.randint(0, asize, int(asize / 10))] = np.nan
    results = dict([(f.__name__, f(a, n)) for f in fns])
    isgood = [[np.array_equal(results[f1], results[f2]) for f1 in fnames] for f2 in fnames]
    pdgood = pd.DataFrame(isgood, columns = fnames, index = fnames)
    if not all([all(x) for x in isgood]):
        print "not all results identical"
        pdb.set_trace()
    return pdgood


def timeone(f):
    """ time one of the functions across the full range of a nd n """
    print "Timing", f.__name__
    Ns = np.array([10**x for x in range(0, 4)]) * 5 # 5 to 5000 window size
    As = [np.random.rand(10 ** x) for x in range(1, 8)] # up to 10 million data data points
    for i in range(len(As)): # 10% of points are always bad
        As[i][np.random.randint(0, len(As[i]), len(As[i]) / 10)] = np.nan
    results = np.array([[Timer(lambda: f(a, n)).timeit(number = 1) if n < len(a) \
                        else np.nan for n in Ns] for a in As])
    pdresults = pd.DataFrame(results, index = [len(x) for x in As], columns = Ns)
    return pdresults


def timeall(fns = funcs):
    """ run timeone for all known funcs """
    testd = dict([(x.__name__, timeone(x)) for x in fns])
    testdf = pd.concat(testd.values(), axis = 0, keys = testd.keys())
    testdf.index.names = ["coder", "asize"]
    testdf.columns.names = ["nsize"]
    testdf.reset_index(inplace = True)
    testdf = pd.melt(testdf, id_vars = ["coder", "asize"])
    return testdf
```

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but how did you make that image?

Comment: @AGML: R ggplot 2 library. Code is included above. Simply export the timeall() results to a csv, bring into R, as a variable (here called ww), and it should work unchanged. Tried for half a day to replicate in Seaborn only to go back to R where graphics still rule supreme.

Comment: From the pic in the question I expected a pretty benchmark overview... You delivered :)

Answer (score 4):

This could also be considered a [morphological dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_%28morphology%29) problem, using here the [`scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html):

```
def dilation(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    s = np.full(n, True, bool)
    return ndimage.binary_dilation(m, structure=s, origin=-(n//2))
```

Note on `origin`: this argument ensures the `structure` (I would call it a *kernel*) starts off a bit to the left of the `input` (your mask `m`). Normally the value at `out[i]` would be the dilation with the center of `structure` (which would be `structure[n//2]`) at `in[i]`, but you want the `structure[0]` to be at `in[i]`.

You can also do this with a kernel that is padded on the left with `False`s, which is what would be required if you used the [`binary_dilation`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#binary-dilation) from [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/):

```
def dilation_skimage(a, n):
    m = np.isnan(a)
    s = np.zeros(2*n - n%2, bool)
    s[-n:] = True
    return skimage.morphology.binary_dilation(m, selem=s)
```

Timing doesn't seem to change too much between the two:

```
dilation_scipy
small:    10 loops, best of 3: 47.9 ms per loop
large: 10000 loops, best of 3: 88.9 µs per loop

dilation_skimage
small:    10 loops, best of 3: 47.0 ms per loop
large: 10000 loops, best of 3: 91.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: Who says the Python scientific ecosystem is not absolutely awesome, and that it does not attract the very best people. Askewchan, you are a master. I have already found your original answer to be very performant for my use case. I am preparing some benchmarks versus looped versions which I will post this evening.

Comment: Haha, thanks for the kind words, @Thomas. It's a pleasure to help. The timings, and therefore your best choice, will depend a lot on the relative sizes of `len(a)`, `np.count_nonzero(m)`, and `n` itself. Do not disregard @AGML's answer, which is faster for some cases.

Comment: Very clever! I'm curious to see the timings, since "do something to a window around some indices" seems like a reasonably common problem.

Comment: How do the arrays look like that you used for timing?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
maskleft = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
maskright = maskleft + n
mask = np.zeros(len(a),dtype=bool)
for l,r in itertools.izip(maskleft,maskright): 
   mask[l:r] = True
```

Or, since n is small, it might be better to loop over it instead:

```
maskleft = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
mask = np.zeros(len(a),dtype=bool)
for i in range(0,n):
  thismask = maskleft+i
  mask[thismask] = True
```

Except for the loop over n, the above is fully vectorized. But the loop is fully parallelizable, so you could be able to get a factor-n speedup using e.g. multiprocessing or Cython, if you're willing to go to the trouble.

Edit: per @askewchan solution 2 can potentially cause out of range errors. It also has indexing problems in the `range(0,n)`. Possible correction:

```
maskleft = np.where(np.isnan(a))[0]
ghost_mask = np.zeros(len(a)+n,dtype=bool)
for i in range(0, n+1):
    thismask = maskleft + i
    ghost_mask[thismask] = True
mask = ghost_mask[:len(ghost_mask)-n]
```

Comment: Nice but we're looping. I was hoping some combo of Numpy, Scipy or Pandas had a clever way of doing this in a vectorized form. I may be being too fussy. Unfortunately I'm already using all the processors in a multiprocessing queue for multiple data series simultaneously. Really what I was hoping was for a nice algebraic sort of way that would run this as fast as possible and perhaps take advantage of AVX registers. I realize I'm being very demanding here..... your loop may well be fast enough and I'll give it a try.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to avoid looping entirely, but provided n is small you should be able to get equivalent performance by parallelizing the loop over n.

Comment: If this is still too slow you're probably getting into Cython territory, unfortunately. Here's a similar problem to get started if this becomes necessary: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2xqlwj/using_npwhere_to_find_subarrays/

Comment: Your first solution is faster than anything I can come up with for a small range in sizes. Your second answer doesn't handle `True` values within `n` of the end properly (makes the index `maskleft + i` out of range).

Comment: See the results below AGML...feel free to change the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) with [`np.bitwise_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([4, 0, 8, 5, 10, 9, np.nan, 1, 4, 9, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 9,
              9, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 2, 6, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 1, np.nan, 10])
m = np.isnan(a)
n = 4
i = np.arange(1, len(m)+1)
ind = np.column_stack([i-n, i]) # may be a faster way to generate this
ind.clip(0, len(m)-1, out=ind)

np.bitwise_or.reduceat(m, ind.ravel())[::2]
```

On your data:

```
print np.column_stack([m, reduced])
[[False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False  True]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]
 [False  True]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same cumsum trick as you would for a running average filter:

```
def cumsum_trick(a, n):
    mask = np.isnan(a)
    cs = np.cumsum(mask)
    cs[n:] -= cs[:-n].copy()
    return cs > 0
```

Unfortunately the additional `.copy()` is needed, because of <s>some buffering that goes on internally</s> the order of operations. It is possible to persuade numpy to apply the subtraction in reverse, but for that to work the `cs` array must have a negative stride:

```
def cumsum_trick_nocopy(a, n):
    mask = np.isnan(a)
    cs = np.cumsum(mask, out=np.empty_like(a, int)[::-1])
    cs[n:] -= cs[:-n]
    out = cs > 0
    return out
```

But this seems fragile and isn't really that much faster anyway.

I wonder if there's a compiled signal processing function somewhere that does this exact operation..

---

For sparse initial masks and small `n` this one is also pretty fast:

```
def index_expansion(a, n):
    mask = np.isnan(a)
    idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
    expanded_idx = idx[:,None] + np.arange(1, n)
    np.put(mask, expanded_idx, True, 'clip')
    return mask
```

Comment: The reason for the need to copy is the order in which `cs` elements are read and written. I confused in-place ufunc application with fancy indexing, which does use some kind of buffering.

Answer (score 2):

A few years late, but I've come up with a fully vectorized solution that requires no loops or copies (besides the mask itself). This solution is a bit (potentially) dangerous because it uses [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html). It's also not as fast as [@swentzel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32728547/2988730).

The idea is to take the mask and create a 2D view of it, where the second dimension is just the elements that follow the current element. Then you can just set an entire column to `True` if the head is `True`. Since you are dealing with a view, setting a column will actually set the following elements in the mask.

Start with the data:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([4, 0, 8, 5, 10, 9, np.nan, 1, 4, 9, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 9,\
              9, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 2, 6, 7, 2, 9, 4, 1, 1, np.nan, 10])
n = 3
```

Now, we will make the mask `a.size + n` elements long, so that you don't have to process the last `n` elements manually:

```
mask = np.empty(a.size + n, dtype=np.bool)
np.isnan(a, out=mask[:a.size])
mask[a.size:] = False
```

Now the cool part:

```
view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(mask, shape=(n + 1, a.size),
                                       strides=mask.strides * 2)
```

That last part is crucial. `mask.strides` is a tuple like `(1,)` (since bools are usually about that many bytes across. Doubling it means that you take a 1-byte step to move one element in *any* dimension.

Now all you need to do is expand the mask:

```
view[1:, view[0]] = True
```

That's it. Now `mask` has what you want. Keep in mind that this only works because the assignment index precedes the last changed value. You could not get away with `view[1:] |= view[0]`.

For benching purposes, it appears that the definition of `n` has changed from the question, so the following function takes that into account:

```
def madphysicist0(a, n):
    m = np.empty(a.size + n - 1, dtype=np.bool)
    np.isnan(a, out=m[:a.size])
    m[a.size:] = False

    v = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(m, shape=(n, a.size), strides=m.strides * 2)
    v[1:, v[0]] = True
    return v[0]
```

**V2**

Taking a leaf out of the existing fastest answer, we only need to copy `log2(n)` rows, not `n` rows:

```
def madphysicist1(a, n):
    m = np.empty(a.size + n - 1, dtype=np.bool)
    np.isnan(a, out=m[:a.size])
    m[a.size:] = False

    v = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(m, shape=(n, a.size), strides=m.strides * 2)

    stop = int(np.log2(n))
    for k in range(1, stop + 1):
        v[k, v[0]] = True
    if (1<<k) < n:
        v[-1, v[(1<<k) - 1]] = True
    return v[0]
```

Since this doubles the size of the mask at every iteration, it works a bit faster than Fibonacci: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/894743/295281

Comment: your madphysicist1 does not pass the allagree() test. I'm going to test only the first routine madphysicist0. You might want to check it and edit it.

Comment: I have benchmarked you and you're fast, but not fast as swenzel1 or moarningstar. Perhaps your madphysicist1 routine would be faster? But as I said it doesn't output correctly. I'll rebench once it does. Here is a link to a chart of the results including you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rntk0wpieobwz9v/madphysicist0_included.png?dl=0

Comment: You seem to be prepending one FALSE too many in runs of FALSE, with madphysicist1(a, n).

Comment: @ThomasBrowne. I'll check it out.