# Get the max of the sum of consecutive non-nans values along an axis in 3D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to vectorize an operation, and I cannot figure out how to optimize it.

Say I have a 3D array *a* of shape (4, 6, 3). I want to sum the consecutively non-nan values over axis 0, and compute the maximum of the newly formed array *b* over axis 0.

```
# a is of shape (6, 4, 3)
a = np.array(
[[[       np.nan,        np.nan,    0.21145476],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   0.11141416,        np.nan,    0.00345888]],

 [[       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,            1.,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,            1.,        np.nan]],
  
 [[       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,    0.43558095],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   0.72669291,        np.nan,        np.nan]],
  
 [[       np.nan,        np.nan,    0.11763977],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,    0.01386668,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   0.41135376,        np.nan,        np.nan]]])
  
# Calculate b to obtain consecutive non-nan sums over axis 0
b = VECTORIZED_FUNCTION(a)

# This is what b should end up being:
b = np.array(
[[[       np.nan,        np.nan,    0.21145476],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   0.11141416,        np.nan,    0.00345888]],

 [[       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,            1.,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,            1.,        np.nan]],
  
 [[       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,    0.43558095],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   0.72669291,        np.nan,        np.nan]],
  
 [[       np.nan,        np.nan,    0.11763977],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,    0.01386668,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   1.13804667,        np.nan,        np.nan]]])

c = np.nanmax(b, axis=0)

# This is what c should end up being:
c = np.array(
  [[      np.nan,        np.nan,    0.21145476],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,            1.,    0.43558095],
  [       np.nan,    0.01386668,        np.nan],
  [       np.nan,        np.nan,        np.nan],
  [   1.13804667,            1.,    0.00345888]])
```

I can make it work with a loop on axis 1 and 2, but this is unrealistically slow for the arrays I'll need to process (1000 arrays of dimensions ~(500, 1500, 800)).

***EDIT1:***

A first (non-loopy) tentative approach leads to:

```
def pad_series(m, n=3):
    # Function adapted from @Swenzel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706135/extend-numpy-mask-by-n-cells-to-the-right-for-each-bad-value-efficiently
    k = m.copy()
    lenM, lenK = 1, 1
    while lenM+lenK < n:
        m[lenM:] |= k[:-lenM]
        m, k = k, m
        lenM, lenK = lenK, lenM+lenK
    k[n-lenM:] |= m[:-n+lenM]
    return k
    
# Select the non nan value in a mask
mask = ~np.isnan(a)
# Get the start of each "series" greater than 1 element along axis 0
runs = np.zeros_like(mask, dtype=bool)
runs[:-1] = mask[:-1] & mask[1:]
# Pad so that you get all the value in the series in an updated mask
runs_2 = pad_series(runs, n=2)
b = np.copy(a)
# Set everything in a copy of a to nan if they're not part of a serie
b[~runs_2] = np.nan
# Sum cumulatively
b = np.nancumsum(b, axis=0)
# Big issue: works only if one "multi-subheatwave" heatwave
c = np.nanmax(np.maximum(a, b), axis=0)
```

So, in my (simplified) example, this edit1 solution works as expected. It is however not generalized as if you have two or more series, the np.nancumsum function will add the second series to the first, etc.

Comment: What is `VECTORIZED_FUNCTION` supposed to be doing here? in the given example, `a` and `b` are identical. perhaps you have a version which is not vectorized as an example?

Comment: Sorry, it may not have been made clear in the question. a and b are not identical, see the "bottom left" value. Basically, the goal is "if 2 or more consecutive non-nans over axis=0, take their sum", which gives you b, and then "take the max of b along axis 0" to get the answer

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bottom left being different earlier... I'm not sure I can easily come up with a totally vectorized answer, but I find mixing `numba` in with the party usually helps a lot

Comment: You should always make an MCVE, with a focus on the M. You don't need a (4, 6, 3) array. It adds nothing to the explanation, and makes it harder to visualize what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I understand it, vectorized operations can't directly do what you want without a pretty significant added complexity. I can however get rid of all but one loop with a fairly straightforward function (assuming I have interpreted your intent correctly).

```
def segmented_cumsum(a):
    b = a.copy() #just use `a` if you want in-place operation
    for i in range(1,len(b)):
        mask = ~np.isnan(b[i-1])
        b[i][mask] += b[i-1][mask]
    return b
```

By only grabbing non-`nan` numbers from the prior slice, if we attempt to sum with a `nan` value in the current slice, it won't matter. Any `nan` values in the current slice will stay `nan`, and any non-nan values will be summed with the value from the prior slice if it was non-`nan`.

This should also benefit some speedup using [`numba`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to compile the loop to LLVM code. `numba` doesn't support all the advanced array slicing that numpy does unfortunately, so we must flatten the array by a dimension for calculation then re-shape it at the end:

```
from numba import njit
@njit("float64[:,:,:](float64[:,:,:])")
def segmented_cumsum(a):
    shape = a.shape
    b = a.copy().reshape(shape[0], -1) #just use `a` if you want in-place operation
    for i in range(1,len(b)):
        mask = ~np.isnan(b[i-1])
        b[i][mask] += b[i-1][mask] #cumsum
    return b.reshape(shape)
```

The first time a `jit`'ed function is called, it will take a second or two to compile, but afterwards will be very fast (about 10x on my machine using your example `a` as input).

Comment: Yep, this looks like it would do it indeed, using the nan properties, brilliant. Using numba is a very good suggestion too, I have yet to do anything with this but it seems like a perfect opportunity for this

Comment: Knowing a little about IEEE 754 is how you know to look for these types of solution (how nan and inf are treated in arithmetic). It is fortunate numpy uses non-signaling nan in this case. vectorization is nothing more than a very efficient loop written in c rather than python. There are some cases things like simd instructions can be used (and likely won't be with numba), but the big win is getting away from python for the heavy compute.