# Numpy fastest way to create mask array around indexes

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have a 1D array:

```
arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, ...], dtype='uint16')
```

I want to create a `mask` array that is `True` anywhere that is +/- `N` indexes of of a value greater than 2, yielding the following (for `N=3`)

```
mask = [F, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, F, F, F, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, ...]
```

(note, I used `T`/`F` for readability's sake)

I need this to be rather fast as my actual array is millions of points long, `N` will likely be something like 500.

Edit: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706135/extend-numpy-mask-by-n-cells-to-the-right-for-each-bad-value-efficiently)

Comment: Note that `arr = [0, 0, ...]` is not an array but a list. Did you mean a list or it is really a Numpy array? If so, what is its `dtype`?

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks, it's an `ndarray` with `dtype=uint16`

Comment: `np.convolve(arr>2, np.full(2*N+1, True), "same")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the elements larger than `2` then set the elements around them to `True`:

```
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0])

N = 3
mask = a > 2
center = np.where(mask)[0]
mask[np.maximum(np.ravel(center - np.arange(1, 1 + N).reshape(-1, 1)), 0)] = True
mask[np.minimum(np.ravel(center + np.arange(1, 1 + N).reshape(-1, 1)), len(a)-1)] = True
```

Thanks @Michael Szczesny for pointing out the edge case. The `maximum` and `minimum` ensures that the index would not (unintentionally) go out of bounds.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a convolution with [`numpy.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) and an array of ones of length 2*N+1 (N on each side plus self) as mask:

```
np.convolve(arr>2, np.ones(2*N+1), mode='same').astyoe(bool)
```

Output:

```
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: It is also to be noted that if you don't cast to `bool` then you even have a count of the number of neighbors.

Comment: convolve is much slower... (my mistake), thank you both!!! also, there is a typeo `astyoe`

Comment: @paime yes, I love convolutions, so powerful ;)

Comment: @joshp You might get faster performance by modifying the np.ones call to `np.ones(2*N+1,dtype='int')` or `np.ones(2*N+1,dtype='bool')`